# ESLint: Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-hook-form

I'm using `react-hook-form`

```
const onSubmit = async (values: IProductType) => {
  const response = await dispatch(createProductType({
    productType: values,
    shopId: shopId as string
  }));
  const newCreatedProductType = response.payload as IProductType;

  if (response.meta.requestStatus === requestStatusSuccess) {
    dispatch(getMessageAction(t('createSuccess', { ns: 'productType', name: values.name }), 'success'));
    dispatch(addProductType(newCreatedProductType));

    if (onCreateSuccess) {
        onCreateSuccess(newCreatedProductType);
    }

    reset();
}
```

};

And passing it on to the `<form>`:

```
//Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

I tried wrapping it in an empty function and that fixed the error, but then the submission quit working:

```
<form onSubmit={() => { handleSubmit(onSubmit) }}>
```

Comment: You found the fix?

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into the same issue.

The following is getting rid of the ESLINT error ***but will result in a refresh***, `preventDefault()` is not getting triggered for some reason.

```js
<form
  onSubmit={void handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
>
```

I solved it by passing a anonymous function with the `event` which you can then use to call on `handleSubmit`.

```js
<form
  onSubmit={(event) =>
    void handleSubmit(onSubmit)(event)
  }
>
```

Comment: To shed some more light on this "some reason": `handleSubmit` takes the React event, calls `preventDefault()` on it, and transforms it into an object with the form values (for easier processing in your handler). Regarding the question what the faulty `void` does: it "deletes" the wrapped method/callback returned by `handleSubmit`, so you set `onSubmit=undefined` effectively. Without any callback, the event's bubbling won't be stopped, and will lead to redirect with the form data as query parameters (`submit` behavior).

Answer (score -5):

Add this rule to your `.eslintrc.json`

```
"rules": {
  "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [2, {
    "checksVoidReturn": {
      "attributes": false
    }
  }]
},
```

Had the same issue and found [this answer](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/8622?sort=old#discussioncomment-4060570) on the react-hook-form github discussions helpful. More info about it in the link