# ESLint reports "Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected"

Tags: reactjs, promise, eslint

I have a React application that is giving a linting error:

```
Promise-returning function provided to attribute
where a void return was expected
.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises
```

The function looks like this

```
      <Button onClick={
        async () => {
          await handleDelete()
        }}
      >
```

I've tried adding `return void` along with a number of different ways to wrap the code and add catch as suggested in various SO posts but none of them worked to resolve the error.

I do not wish to disable the rule without understanding why - and once I do it will probably be to remove or disable the rule in the lint config.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74190256/eslint-promise-returning-function-provided-to-attribute-where-a-void-return-was (There are several posts with this ESLint message).

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches here:

1. You could either wrap the function in an *IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)*,

```js
     <Button onClick={
         () => {
             void (async () => {
                 await handleDelete()
             })();
          }
      }>
```

You can learn more about IIFE on: [MDN Official Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

2. Or, you could disable the `no-misused-promises` rule.

For project wide, add rule in `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
    "error",
    {
      "checksVoidReturn": false
    }
  ]
}
```

To disable this inline, comment this above the particular occurrence to ignore the error.

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises
```

You could read about it more on: [GitHub ESLint Docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md)

Comment: nice. I might combine the eslint config rule, using your example of `checksVoidReturn`  with `overrides`  for specific files to target the react componetns only

Comment: Great, I hope the solution worked for you. The reason the error occurred because onClick expects a function which returns `void` but void async functions returns `Promise<void>`. But when you wrap it in a void IIFE, you ignore return value of the inner async function and ensuring that the outer arrow function returns void, as expected by onClick.

Comment: Yeah, great. I'm debating whether to have to use the code style through the react app or whether the config route will work as that is usually my preference for cleaner code - with the caveat that it doesn't fail in error reporting, etc for quality code

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you can safely skip using `async`, because there is no need for either `handleDelete` result or async flow control

```
      <Button onClick={
        () => {
          handleDelete()
        }}
      >
```

In other scenarios the documentation for the `no-misused-promises` rule suggests 2 approaches:

- Use an async IIFE wrapper

```
      <Button onClick={
        () => {
          void (async () => {
            await handleDelete();
          })();
        }}
      >
```

- Name the async wrapper to call it later

```
      <Button onClick={
        () => {
          const handle = async () => {
            await handleDelete()
          }
          handle()
        }}
      >
```

ref: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-misused-promises/#checksvoidreturn